# How to get worlds back after reinstalling Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I deleted Minecraft to update it then I put it back onto my iPad. It’s bedrock edition. When I signed into my account, all my worlds were gone. Do I get them back?

Comment: None of these worlds were backed up

Comment: Why did you need to delete the app to update it?

Comment: Unfortunately if you didn't back up the worlds, then deleting the app probably wiped them.

Comment: it definitely wiped them. Deleting the minecraft app will delete all your worlds if you're not backing them up manually.